# Sentence with and without IS and ARE

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

I found specially in spoken english speaker omits Is and are.
Is there any specific grammar rule for this? 
E.g.

Are you ok? And   You ok?

You are always busy. And You always busy.

You are writing this since 2 yrs.   And  You writing this since 2 yrs.

Comment: Your examples sound contrived and unnatural to me. If I was asking two people if they were okay, I'd probably ask it like this: "Are you okay? And you?" Your second example would sound more like: "You are always busy. You, too."

Answer (score 3):

The only time I can think this common is with questions asked directly to a person or persons,

> You coming? (Are you coming?)
>
> We ready? (Are we ready?)
>
> We all good?  (either "Are all of us 'good'?" or "Are you and I completely OK with each other?")

It's colloquial and informal, appropriate to use in casual conversation.  I would say it's not appropriate to use in business meetings or the courtroom, but both are much less formal situations than they used to be (at least in the United States).

Answer (score 1):

> You always busy

might be accepted in [AAVE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_American_Vernacular_English), where the copula can be dropped in the present tense and first or second person. But it is not standard American English, so I wouldn't recommend using to an English learner.

> You OK?

is pretty common in informal situations. I suspect this has been adopted from AAVE by other Americans.

> You are writing this since 2 years

and

> You writing this since 2 years

are both non-standard. I'd say "You've been writing this for 2 years." Notice that in your first two examples, "are" is the [copula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(linguistics)), while in this example it's part of the present progressive of *to write*, so you shouldn't expect it to behave the same.